# How do I detect in a service worker fetch that the request is for the manifest's start_url?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, fetch-api

I have a PWA, which has a [`manifest.json`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) with a [`start_url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#start_url).

I have a service worker with a `fetch` event that only caches certain requests.
This is done in the service worker by overriding the response to proxy from the cache (TypeScript for clarity):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event: FetchEvent) => {
    // This MUST be synchronous until respondWith is called

    const cache = isCachable(event.request);
    if (!isCachable)
        return; // Don't proxy, let the network request continue

    // Kick off a promise to check the cache, and clone/cache the response otherwise
    const proxy: Promise<Response> = cacheResponse(event);

    event.respondWith(proxy);
}
```

I want to cache the `start_url`, which means `isCachable` above needs to be able to tell that the value of `start_url` is the relative route being requested.

I can load the `manifest.json` in the SW but that feels really clunky. I can hard code the values in the SW, but then I need to update two places if config changes.

In the `fetch` handler `event.request.url` is absolute, but the `start_url` is relative to the `manifest.json` - so, for instance, I might have:

- `manifest.json`: `{ "start_url": "appshell" ... }`
- Web site gets deployed to `www.example.com/folder/` (but might be deployed to `sub.example.com` or `www.example.com/a/b` or whatever)
- Online user visits site, either visits everything or install script caches direct.
- Later, same user visits offline.
- The fetch above fires with `event.request.url === 'www.example.com/folder/appshell'`
- I need the `isCachable` function to be able to tell that resource should be cached synchronously. It needs to determine that `www.example.com/folder/appshell` is `appshell` (resolve the relative link) and that `appshell` is set as `start_url` (read the manifest).

Obviously, all this *can* be hard coded. However, every PWA needs respond from the cache for `start_url`, so this can't be a new problem. Before I reinvent the wheel is there a better way or something I'm missing?

So...

- Given that service workers need the manifest, is there a good way to get the manifest's config in the worker?
- Is there a way to resolve the relative link for comparison with the manifest?

Comment: You are talking about Web App manifest right? Not about the extension's one?

Comment: And is your question only about resolving relative paths? If so, do you want to resolve it relatively to the SW or from the document that made the request?

Comment: @Kaiido there's only one `manifest.json` that applies to service workers. Yes this is a progressive web app and not a browser extension. The `start_url` is relative to the manifest. The `event.request.url` passed to the `fetch` handler in the service worker is absolute, the cache in a service worker is relative to the service worker. I don't need to figure out relative links anywhere else, this question is just about the specific case of the start URL, which needs to be cached by the service worker.

Comment: Then why do you keep using the tag that is meant for web extensions? And the documentation link you edited is out of date, since then a new extension .webmanifest has been officialised.

Comment: @Kaiido because this is specifically a question about the manifest.json, and the service worker context is much more commonly understood than the extension one (guess which is the top hit on search?), and both are variants of the same thing.

Comment: ... the stack overflow tag [tag:anifest.json] is about extensions. People following it know nothing about WPA. If you wish, you can create a [webmanifest] tag, but don't missuses the other one.

Comment: And as I understand it, your question is not that much related to this webmanifest either, but is more about how to resolve relative URLs from within a Worker. I guess you know the structure of your files don't you? So you might be able to hard code the path relative to the SW inside the SW code. From there I can help you to make that relative path absolute, but your question is so broadly written that I'm not sure what you need exactly...

Comment: @kaiido yes, as stated in the questions there are workarounds within the service worker, but that's a lot of work to maintain and feels like reinventing the wheel. Also, as I don't know where it will be installed I'll have some nasty cludges or additional config (as there's no `import.meta`). Every PWA _must_ cache the manifest's start URL for offline mode to work at all, so I'm _highly_ unlikely to be the first person to try and solve this problem.

Comment: Ah I think I see your problem: you are probably confused about how pwa and particularly a2hs works. A2hs is really just a link app, something like just `./your_browser --url $yoursiteorigin$start_url --...` command line. Nothing more (well also some icons), your *app* is still your website. Once launched, it is the same as if your user did navigate there. So the path are still relative to your original website, since it is your original website. The SW that will provide the cache is just the one that runs on your website, so just hardcode all the assets you wish to cache, as everyone does.

Comment: @Kaiido no, I get all of that. The problem is that in the `fetch` handler of the service worker `event.request.url` is absolute. Depending on where the app is hosted this might be `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/folder` or `sub.example.com/folder/sub` or whatever. I need a service worker hosted at, say, `www.example.com/folder`, and with manifest `{ "start_url": "app-shell" ...`  to know to cache `www.example.com/folder/app-shell` but not `www.example.com/folder/api`.

Comment: But I don't get it... You are caching it only when the user navigates there? That's the kind of content you'll want to [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/addAll) in your cache manually, from the *install* event without waiting for a *fetch* one. URLs passed to `Cache.add` or `Cache.addAll` can be relative.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, the install event is fine. I can cache the `start_url` and [lighthouse reckons it's good to go as a PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/cache-contains-start_url). However, when an offline user starts the app the first thing that happens is a fetch request to the absolute URL, and if that isn't served from the cache it can't load. I need to know from `event.request.url`, _before_ I `await` the open or lookup on the cache, whether this path is one that can be cached or one that isn't proxies by the service worker.

Comment: Could you try to set up clearly in your question your current case, with the structure of your assets what your SW is doing both in install and fetch, how the path might change and what's the issue you are facing. I have troubles getting the whole picture. Like here, if an offline user starts the app, the first thing that should happen is that they get the first page from SW cache, there should not be a fetch.

Comment: @Kaiido The service worker has a cache but _nothing_ is pulled from it automatically - you have to subscribe to the `fetch` event and override it with `FetchEvent.respondWith`. You have to know _before_ you call `respondWith` whether you're going to check the cache, as any promise before then (and the cache check is a promise) loses the chance to proxy the request and the `fetch` continues to the network. I need to _syncronously_ know that the `event.request.url` is something that could be in the cache before I go and asynchronously check the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this, but it's nasty and I'm sure there's a better way.

In particular I'm hard-coding in the manifest inline (I could `fetch` it, but that's nasty too).

```
const manifest = { start_url: 'appshell' };
```

Then I use `self.location` to get the path of the service worker. This includes the file name, so I trim that off the end:

```
// if file is 'sw.js' that's 5 chars off the end
const applicationRoot = new URL(self.location.href.slice(0, -5) + manifest.start_url);
```

Then I can check against this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event: FetchEvent) => {
    // This MUST be synchronous until respondWith is called

    const url = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (url.pathname === applicationRoot.pathname) {
        // Request is for the start_url, always return something so the PWA starts offline
        event.respondWith(...):
    }

    // ... see question for rest
});
```

This is clunky, but at least it can always serve the cached `start_url` without caching everything else, so it is the accepted answer for now. I'd love to see a better way of doing this, ideally without hard coding/fetching the `manifest.json` so that config changes there don't require a new service worker.